# Jupyter Notebook not importing Geopandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, geopandas

I try to import Geopandas on my Jupyter Notebook but it says that there is no module named geopandas. However, when  I run !pip list it appears in the list so it must be installed in the kernel.

```
!pip list 
from eurostatapiclient import EurostatAPIClient
import json
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as mplt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter, MaxNLocator, IndexLocator
import shapely 
import geopandas as gpd
import requests
import io, os, re, sys
import warnings
import copy, functools
import zipfile
import folium
from folium import plugins as foliump
import branca.colormap as bcm
```

The output is:

Package                       Version

---

```
    alabaster                     0.7.12
    argh                          0.26.2
    argon2-cffi                   20.1.0
    astroid                       2.3.3
    atomicwrites                  1.4.0
    attrs                         19.3.0
    autopep8                      1.5.3
    Babel                         2.8.0
    backcall                      0.2.0
    bcrypt                        3.1.7
    bleach                        3.1.5
    branca                        0.4.1
    brotlipy                      0.7.0
    certifi                       2020.6.20
    cffi                          1.14.0
    chardet                       3.0.4
    click                         7.1.2
    click-plugins                 1.1.1
    cligj                         0.5.0
    cloudpickle                   1.5.0
    colorama                      0.4.3
    cryptography                  2.9.2
    cycler                        0.10.0
    decorator                     4.4.2
    defusedxml                    0.6.0
    diff-match-patch              20200713
    docutils                      0.16
    entrypoints                   0.3
    eurostatapiclient             0.2.5
    **Fiona                         1.8.4**
    flake8                        3.8.3
    folium                        0.11.0
    future                        0.18.2
    **GDAL                          2.3.3**
    **geopandas**                   0.6.3**
    idna                          2.8
    imagesize                     1.2.0
    importlib-metadata            1.6.1
    intervaltree                  3.0.2
    ipykernel                     5.3.2
    ipython                       7.16.1
    ipython-genutils              0.2.0
    isort                         4.3.21
    jedi                          0.17.1
    Jinja2                        2.11.2
    json5                         0.9.5
    jsonschema                    3.2.0
    jupyter-client                6.1.6
    jupyter-core                  4.6.3
    jupyterlab                    2.1.5
    jupyterlab-server             1.2.0
    keyring                       21.2.1
    kiwisolver                    1.2.0
    lazy-object-proxy             1.5.0
    MarkupSafe                    1.1.1
    matplotlib                    3.3.0
    mccabe                        0.6.1
    mistune                       0.8.4
    mkl-fft                       1.1.0
    mkl-random                    1.1.1
    mkl-service                   2.3.0
    munch                         2.5.0
    nbconvert                     5.6.1
    nbformat                      5.0.7
    notebook                      6.1.1
    numpy                         1.19.1
    numpydoc                      1.1.0
    packaging                     20.4
    pandas                        0.23.4
    pandocfilters                 1.4.2
    paramiko                      2.7.1
    parso                         0.7.0
    pathtools                     0.1.2
    pexpect                       4.8.0
    pickleshare                   0.7.5
    Pillow                        7.2.0
    pip                           20.1.1
    pluggy                        0.13.1
    prometheus-client             0.8.0
    prompt-toolkit                3.0.5
    psutil                        5.7.0
    pycodestyle                   2.6.0
    pycparser                     2.20
    pydocstyle                    5.0.2
    pyflakes                      2.2.0
    Pygments                      2.6.1
    pylint                        2.4.4
    PyNaCl                        1.4.0
    pyOpenSSL                     19.1.0
    pyparsing                     2.4.7
    **pyproj                        1.9.6**
    pyrsistent                    0.16.0
    PySocks                       1.7.1
    python-dateutil               2.8.1
    python-jsonrpc-server         0.3.4
    python-language-server        0.34.1
    pytz                          2020.1
    pywin32                       227
    pywin32-ctypes                0.2.0
    pywinpty                      0.5.7
    PyYAML                        5.3.1
    pyzmq                         19.0.1
    QDarkStyle                    2.8.1
    QtAwesome                     0.7.2
    qtconsole                     4.7.5
    QtPy                          1.9.0
    requests                      2.21.0
    rope                          0.17.0
    Rtree                         0.9.4
    scipy                         1.5.1
    seaborn                       0.10.1
    Send2Trash                    1.5.0
    setuptools                    49.2.0.post20200714
    **Shapely                       1.7.0**
    six                           1.15.0
    snowballstemmer               2.0.0
    sortedcontainers              2.2.2
    Sphinx                        3.1.2
    sphinxcontrib-applehelp       1.0.2
    sphinxcontrib-devhelp         1.0.2
    sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp        1.0.3
    sphinxcontrib-jsmath          1.0.1
    sphinxcontrib-qthelp          1.0.3
    sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.4
    spyder                        4.1.4
    spyder-kernels                1.9.2
    terminado                     0.8.3
    testpath                      0.4.4
    toml                          0.10.1
    tornado                       6.0.4
    traitlets                     4.3.3
    ujson                         1.35
    urllib3                       1.24.3
    watchdog                      0.10.3
    wcwidth                       0.2.5
    webencodings                  0.5.1
    wheel                         0.34.2
    win-inet-pton                 1.1.0
    wincertstore                  0.2
    wrapt                         1.12.1
    yapf                          0.30.0
    zipp                          3.1.0
```

---

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
13 from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter, MaxNLocator, IndexLocator
14 import shapely
---> 15 import geopandas as gpd
16 import requests
17 import io, os, re, sys

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopandas'

Comment: are you sure shapely is ok?  geopandas depends on that and it looks problematic in your list

Comment: Why does it look problematic?

Comment: look at what you included `**Shapely                       1.7.0**` only item that has ** in it...  I've also failed to install shapely before due too the number of wheels it depends on

Comment: I added that on purpouse to show that I had that libraries (the needed ones for Geopandas) on the pip list they had not that

Comment: what OS are you working on?  I've successfully installed on MacOS, Ubuntu, AWS EB, Azure, GCloud.  But could not get it to work on raspian - mostly I gave up because wheels don't exist for shapely and C compilation time would have been 24hrs

Comment: I'm working on windows 10 Home

Comment: my suggestion is start with a nice clean virtual env.  I'm quite strict about never installing any packages outside a venv so have full control of package versions